# Como reproducir archivos de audio en Exoplayer

Tags: java, android

Buenas.

He usado la clase Media Player que tiene android pero tira algunos errores al reproducir algunos tipos de archivos asi que intente con Exoplayer, pero la poca documentacion que he visto no me han ayudado mucho he he visto videos e incluso he seguido la guia de desarrollador en su pagina oficial: https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/guide.html, pero nada quisiera saber si saben como poder reproducir archivos de audio por ahora.

**Codigo**

```
SimpleExoPlayer player;       
String audio = "/sdcard/Music/Mr.Chu.mp3";

    ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory=new DefaultExtractorsFactory();
    MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(Uri.parse(audio),
            new DefaultDataSourceFactory(context,Util.getUserAgent(context,"exoplayer1")),
            new DefaultExtractorsFactory(),
            null,
            null);
    player.prepare(mediaSource);
    player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
```

Comment: No aportas detalles como que tipo de errores tienes. En la misma guía vienen ejemplos https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/guide.html ¿Cual sería la duda o problema  al realizar el ejemplo?

Comment: ya lo edito en base  a la respuesta de Danni

Answer (score 1):

Puedes preparar audio de la siguiente manera:

```
mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(Uri.parse(radioUrl),
            dataSourceFactory,
            extractorsFactory,
            null,
            null);
    player.prepare(mediaSource);
```

Y para reproducirlo/pausarlo:

```
player.setPlayWhenReady(true/stop);
```

Comment: ¿Que es dataSourceFactory y dataSourceFactory? porque no agregarlo a la respuesta, ¿Como obtengo mediaSource?

Comment: No me funciono Danni podrias ser mas especifico, cuando intente crear los dos primeros parametros(Factory) me tiraba errores, asi los cree de la nada